# Surfaces where all four feets chairs stand

Tags: surfaces

It's well known that a three feet chair can stand correctly on any (regular enough) surface (let alone the intersection between the chair and the surface!and chairs orientation).

How about four feets chairs. I obviously found plane and sphere. I tried to find them all but wasn't able to do so.

Nb : chairs can be any size.

Any hint?

Comment: Do you want the chair to be able to stand *anywhere* on the surface (sphere) , or do you want at least *one* spot on your surface where your chair can stand (4-sided pyramid)?

Comment: Have look at the video on http://www.spiegel.de/wissenschaft/technik/mathematik-mathetrick-stoppt-wackelnden-tisch-im-biergarten-a-987096.html.

Comment: Anywhere on the surface

Comment: Micheal Hoppe The unevenness of floor should be more than than the difference of fourth leg from the plane of other three legs for rotation of chair to be effective, Right?

Comment: Quite cool but incomplete answer I guess

Comment: That  was a comment about the Spiegel.de article.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the leg tips form in 3-space a square with diagonal $d$. Then there can be no third example of such a surface. This is because of rotation requirement:

A hollow cylinder of diameter $d$ and negligible thickness needs to contact ( along a tangent cone of the sphere or plane ) on the surface at its cylinder end.